# Xamarin iOS: Async / Await in DidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, async-await

How should I await a Task in `DidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions` which has no Task returning signature?

```
bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
```

I have to await an initialization Task of a DataManager from my PCL in the plattform specific project. In the Android specific project I can add the `async` modifier to the main method which returns `void`. But the iOS main method returns `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@apineda is totally right that you *shouldn't* be doing this. However, if you **HAVE** to...

You can call `.GetAwaiter()` and `.GetResult()` on your Task.

Example:

```
...
public Task<string> GetSomeStringAsync();
...
var myString = GetSomeStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
...
```

Then you'll get the data you need. Be careful not to break your 17 second timeout!

Comment: Thank you for your immeditate response. I will do the init inside the PCL Application class.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't await any initialization in this method since this one has a limited time to respond back, which if I am not wrong it's 24 seconds. After that time your application will be killed by the system.

I do suggestion instead to add a "splashscreen" as your first ViewController, if you need this to be done in the Platform specific project. There you can make any initialization and even add some nice animation to let the user know. Or you can have this initialization Page in the Xamarin.Forms project and transition from there to your current MainPage once the initialization is completed.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. I will do the init in the PCL in the Application class.